# Mailman install to VPS with no SSH access

Tags: vps, installation, mailman

I have a VPS with only FTP and HTTP access.
There is no SSH acces.

Is it possible to install Mailman there with what I have?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, most likely this is not possible, as you  can't change the relevant configuration files etc.